# What are the differences between LDAP and Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

What are the differences between LDAP and Active Directory?

Answer (score 462):

Active Directory is a database based system that provides authentication, directory, policy, and other services in a Windows environment

LDAP (Lightweight Directory Access Protocol) is an application protocol for querying and modifying items in directory service providers like Active Directory, which supports a form of LDAP.

Short answer: AD is a directory services database, and LDAP is one of the protocols you can use to talk to it.

Answer (score 111):

LDAP is a standard, AD is Microsoft's (proprietary) implementation (and more). [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) has a good article that delves into the specifics. I found [this document](ftp://ftp.uni-duisburg.de/LDAP/Adam-Eval1-0.pdf) with a very detailed evaluation of AD from an LDAP perspective.

Comment: Thanks for the links.  The PDF document, while informative, seems to broadcast negative sentiment towards Microsoft. While I assume the factual statements are correct, I found the tone distracting and it made them sound less than objective.  Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Not really an exact answer. LDAP is a protocol to access directory server, while Microsoft AD is an implementation of directory server.

Comment: @Mark: Anti-Microsoft sentiments are common in Europe and especially in Germany and this should be factored into your interpretation of the document.

Comment: @MarkBennett From my (very quick) reading it appears their conclusions were that LDAP had security issues and was being pushed by a political agenda which was profit rather than security driven. I think using the term 'negative tone' is an understatement but, yes, Wayne Werner that's why I also read the document!

Answer (score 41):

Lightweight Directory Access Protocol or LDAP, is a standards based specification for interacting with directory data. Directory Services can implement support of LDAP to provide interoperability among 3rd party applications.

Active Directory is Microsoft's implementation of a directory service that, among other protocols, supports LDAP to query it's data.

While it supports LDAP, Active Directory provides a host of extensions and conveniences, such as password expiration and account lockout.

Answer (score 30):

**Short Summary**

`Active Directory` is a directory services implemented by Microsoft, and it supports `Lightweight Directory Access Protocol` (LDAP).

**Long Answer**

Firstly, one needs to know what's `Directory Service`.

Directory Service is a software system that stores, organises, and provides access to information in a computer operating system's directory. In software engineering, a directory is a map between names and values. It allows the lookup of named values, similar to a dictionary.

For more details, read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_service

Secondly,as one could imagine, different vendors implement all kinds of forms of directory service, which is harmful to multi-vendor interoperability.

Thirdly, so in the 1980s, the ITU and ISO came up with a set of standards - X.500, for directory services, initially to support the requirements of inter-carrier electronic messaging and network name lookup.

Fourthly, so based on this standard, Lightweight Directory Access Protocol, LDAP, is developed. It uses the TCP/IP stack and a string encoding scheme of the X.500 Directory Access Protocol (DAP), giving it more relevance on the Internet.

Lastly, based on this LDAP/X.500 stack, Microsoft implemented a modern directory service for Windows, originating from the X.500 directory, created for use in Exchange Server. And this implementation is called `Active Directory`.

So in a short summary, `Active Directory` is a directory services implemented by Microsoft, and it supports `Lightweight Directory Access Protocol` (LDAP).

PS[0]: This answer heavily copies content from the wikipedia page listed above.

PS[1]: To know why it may be better use directory service rather just using a relational database, read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_service#Comparison_with_relational_databases

Answer (score 26):

Active Directory isn't just an implementation of LDAP by Microsoft, that is only a small part of what AD is.  Active Directory is (in an overly simplified way) a service that provides LDAP based authentication with Kerberos based Authorization.

Of course their LDAP and Kerberos implementations in AD are not exactly 100% interoperable with other LDAP/Kerberos implementations...

Answer (score 24):

Active directory is a directory service provider, where you can add new user to a directory, remove or modify, specify privilages, assign policy etc. Its just like a phone directory where every person have a unique contact number. Every thing in AD(Active Directory) are considered as Objects and every object is given a Unique ID.(similar to a unique contact number in a phone directory.

Ldap is a protocol specially designed for directory service providers. Windows server OS uses AD as a directory server, AIX which is a UNIX version by IBM uses Tivoli directory server. Both of them uses LDAP protocol for interacting with directory.

Apart from protocol there are LDAP servers, LDAP browsers too.

Answer (score 5):

active directory is the directory service database to store the organizational based data,policy,authentication etc whereas ldap is the protocol used to talk to the directory service database that is ad or adam.

Answer (score 5):

LDAP sits on top of the TCP/IP stack and controls internet directory access. It is environment agnostic.

AD & ADSI is a COM wrapper around the LDAP layer, and is Windows specific.

You can see Microsoft's explanation
[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: There's a problem in Microsoft's explanation. Quote: 

Microsoft provides the Active Directory Service Interfaces (ADSI) for developing client-side directory service applications. 

ADSI consists of a directory service model and a set of COM interfaces. These interfaces enable development of network directory service access applications.

ADSI uses an LDAP provider to communicate with Active Directory. 
ADSI can also access Novell NetWare Directory Services. 
ADSI can communicate with various directory services by using their native providers.
---------
NetWare as opposed to AD or to LDAP?

Comment: NDS is a directory protocol used by Netware. There is actually a NDS provider for ADSI.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772204(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: AD is a server. ADSI is a COM wrapper. NDS is a product and it uses LDAP. @jwilleke

Answer (score 3):

https://jumpcloud.com/blog/difference-between-ldap-and-active-directory/

Realistically, there are probably more differences than similarities between the two directory solutions. Microsoft’s AD is largely a directory for Windows users, devices, and applications. AD requires a Microsoft Domain Controller to be present and when it is, users are able to single sign-on to Windows resources that live within the domain structure.

LDAP, on the other hand, has largely worked outside of the Windows structure focusing on the Linux / Unix environment and with more technical applications. LDAP doesn’t have the same concepts of domains or single sign-on. LDAP is largely implemented with open source solutions and as a result has more flexibility than AD.

Another critical difference between LDAP and Active Directory is how AD and LDAP each approach device management. AD manages Windows devices through and Group Policy Objects (GPOs). A similar concept doesn’t exist within LDAP. Both LDAP and AD are highly different solutions and as a result many organization must leverage both to serve different purposes.

This is why there’s an obvious opportunity for innovation. Why leverage and manage two complete systems, when one system can effectively merge the two?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of systems that support LDAP to talk to them, not just Active Directory.

Sun, IBM, Novell all have directory services that are very effective as LDAP servers.

Answer (score 0):

Active Directory is a super-set of the LDAP protocol.  Depending on how the organization uses Active Directory, your LDAP search/set queries may or may not work.