# LDAP Directory and Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I heard LDAP is a learning curve. If I wanted to go with a LDAP Directory solution because I want to use the LDAP protocol, and I already know Active Directory, wouldn't that be quite easy to setup?

Comment: Yeah. I'd say it's about 43 difficulty units.

Comment: Don't let the bullies intimidate you, Mike. None of us can be an expert about every single thing in development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Active Directory uses the LDAP protocol, so it isn't as different as you may think.

You might want to read this very popular SO question:

[What are the differences between LDAP and Active Directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663402/what-are-the-differences-between-ldap-and-active-directory)